# Assign values in a dataframe column based on another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DF that looks like this.

| Index | Strike |
| --- | --- |
| 190 | 92 |
| 192 | 93 |
| 194 | 96 |
| 196 | 98 |

I want to add a new column dK.
The logic is
dK = next row strike - prev row strike;
for 1st row it is next row strike - current row strike
for last row, it is current row strike - prev row strike

| Index | Strike | dK |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 190 | 92 | 1 |
| 192 | 93 | 4 |
| 194 | 96 | 5 |
| 196 | 98 | 2 |

How can I do this in Python?

Comment: Since you're talking about a dataframe, I'm assuming you're using `pandas`? Have you looked at `pandas.DataFrame.diff`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Grismar. I did start by using diff but found it quickly became inelegant. May be I wasn't doing it properly.

Eg. In this dataframe, if type=put, new col value = abs(nextrowstrike-currentrow), whereas if type=call, new col value = abs(currentrowstrike-prevrow). So in this case, the col comes out to be: 10, 5, 5, 5, 6, 4

type       strike     
put        250
put        260
put        265
call        270
call        276
call        280

I ended up adding 2 columns (1 with diff (periods=-1) and one simply diff and then assigning based on type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.Series.rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rolling.html):

```
>>> df.Strike.rolling(3, 2, True).apply(lambda x: x.iloc[-1] - x.iloc[0])
0    1.0
1    4.0
2    5.0
3    2.0
Name: Strike, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Hi Pablo, thanks so much - this is a very elegant solution! Are we able to specify diff. operations for when the window size used is 3 Vs 2? Eg. If for all except first and last rows, logic was (next row - prev row)/ 2 whereas for 1st and last row it was next-current and current-prev.

Comment: @darkforce Hi! that specific case case can be done by dividing the difference by 2 (`lambda x: (x.iloc[-1] - x.iloc[0])/2`). Note that your logic can be reduced to using the last and first elements (indices `[-1]` and `[0]`) of every window, it doesn't matter if the window size is 3 or 2.

Comment: @darkforce E.g. for the window containing `[92, 93]` you'll get `93 - 92` i.e. next - current. In the other hand, for the window `[96, 98]` you'll get `98-96` i.e. current - prev. In any other case, you'll get next - prev since the window will be of size 3

Comment: Hi @Pablo C, the objective is to find the avg distance from current strike to the prev and next strike. In the case of first and last strike, this reduces to simply the absolute diff between current and next/prev strike.

If I use (x.iloc[-1] - x.iloc[0])/2, then we get: 1/2, 4/2, 5/2 and 2/2, whereas we need 1, 4/2, 5/2 and 2. In essence, for cases where window size is 2, we need (x.iloc[-1] - x.iloc[0]) whereas for cases where window size is 3, we need (x.iloc[-1] - x.iloc[0])/2

This is why I was asking if the operating can be custom to the window size? Apologies if I have been unclear.

Comment: @darkforce in that case you can divide by `x.size -1`

Comment: @darkforce I know that isn't exactly what you're asking for, but my point is in many cases there's a smart way of solving the problem with math tricks. In the other hand, if you can't figure it out a way to do it, you can use a more sophisticated function instead of a lambda function, i.e., a function defined with `def` and conditionals inside it.

Comment: Cheers @Pablo C

Answer (score 0):

Whether this is inelegant is a matter of opinion perhaps, but it does deliver:

```
from pandas import DataFrame

data = [
    {'index': 190, 'strike': 92},
    {'index': 192, 'strike': 93},
    {'index': 194, 'strike': 96},
    {'index': 196, 'strike': 98}
]

df = DataFrame(data)
strike_diff = df['strike'].diff(1).fillna(0)
df['dK'] = (strike_diff + strike_diff.shift(-1).fillna(0)).astype(int)
```

Since `.diff(1)` computes the difference between consecutive lines, these differences are shifted by one position and then added, to get the sum of distances with the previous and next lines.

`.fillna(0)` replaces values that aren't defined with 0 and `.astype(int)` is only there because your example had integers.

Note: this does assume you want the sum of the distances to the previous and next values. Consider:

```
data = [
    {'index': 190, 'strike': 92},
    {'index': 192, 'strike': 93},
    {'index': 194, 'strike': 91}
]
```

If you don't want `3` for index `192` in this case, but `1`, you could use `.diff(2)` and shift that by one, and compute the first and last value manually.

Comment: Thanks @Grismar that's actually v clever!